# How to connect to the internet in Back Track 4?

Tags: internet-connection, backtrack

Can someone help me connect to internet via ethernet in backtrack 4 final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not getting an IP assigned automatically. Try running:

```
ifconfig eth0
```

and see if you have an address assigned to that interface. It should say something similar to

```
inet addr:192.168.1.23
```

if it doesn't then you should run:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.23
```

to set it manually.

Note: I've assumed your network is 192.168.1.0 and that the IP 192.168.1.20 is available. You should probably change that to suit your needs.

Comment: see Eric J's post...

Answer (score 0):

Internet usually works in Back Track 4 for me without problems.

What you have to remember is that this will change from machine to machine, it is most likely that Back Track simply does not have the correct drivers for your wired or wireless connection by default.

I would take a look at the [forums](http://forums.remote-exploit.org/backtrack-4-pre-final/) and try to ask for help on adding a driver.

Alternatively, it could be something as simple as the network you are connecting to does not support DHCP and you simply need to manually assign an address.

Without knowing your machine, I can't really advise further.

Comment: do you have to do anything for it? or does it just work?

Comment: @user38008 Depends where I am connecting from. It does not have my wireless drivers built in, but when I run it through RJ45, it works fine out the box if there is DHCP.... I also carry a wireless USB stick which it does have the drivers for.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to getting connected is just to run the the DHCP client.

$ dhclient

It will simply find and ask the DHCP server on your network for an available IP address.
It will assign you an IP and add the appropriate routes to the routing table for you as well.
It will also configure your setting to add the appropriate DNS that has been specified for your network.

@kirbuchi's post: This is a start, but it won't completely work, because it is still missing the other half. You can give it an IP address, but likely when you try to connect to a remote it will give a time exceeded message. This is simply because the routing table is still incomplete and it does not know where to send traffic anywhere else other than to an IP address on the local network, given that you know the IP address at all. If you want to use the computer's hostname, well you're out of luck on that, too. You haven't specified what/where your DNS is yet either. For the easiest method, please look at my answer post for this solution probably will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your Ethernet cards device name is eth0 an you have a dhcp enabled router/server

First you need to start networking

```
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

Then you need to get an ip address

```
dhclient eth0
```

If that suceeds you should be able to browse the net.